# Resizing label text in PyQt5 Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm currently making a GUI application in PyQt5 Designer and I'm having problems getting the text of labels and pushbuttons to resize with the labels or pushbuttons. I've been able to get the pushbuttons and labels to resize with the window using PyQt5 Designer's layout feature, but just can't get the text to resize.

Thanks!
Ky

Comment: Qt doesn't support that. You might do it programmatically, but it's just your own choice to set the font size based on the overall size. Be aware that doing it without awareness of the underlying issues might cause problems (most probably, recursion, with the window constantly increasing its size indefinitely). Also, from a desktop UX perspective, that would probably be a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's bad UX design, but I do this all the time. My old eyes want everything to be big. My trick is to add font size commands to the resizeEvent of the main window. Here is a minimal example

Python code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont, )
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import sys

form_class = uic.loadUiType('resize.ui')[0]

class Example(QMainWindow, form_class):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # calculate scale factor height (sfh) and scale factor width (sfw) based on
        # minimumHeight and minimumWidth of centralWidget
        sfh = float(self.centralWidget().height())/float(self.centralWidget().minimumHeight())
        sfw = float(self.centralWidget().width())/float(self.centralWidget().minimumWidth())
        sf = min(sfh,sfw)  # scale factor. how much to increase/decrease font size

        font = QFont("Arial")
        font.setPointSizeF(int(sf*10.))

        for widget in self.findChildren((QLabel, QLineEdit)):
            # for more complicated MainWindow, add more widgets to tuple
            # argument
            widget.setFont(font)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ui file (resize.ui):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>160</width>
    <height>211</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>160</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>ResizeExample</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>this is a test</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Do you by chance know if there's a way to solve this in PyQt5's Designer?

Comment: @KyJames No, Designer is to create a static basic UI to start with.

Comment: @bfris This isn't very effective, for various reasons. First of all, it is completely based on the aspect ratio of the minimum size of the central widget: if the ratio is different, the result is that the font would actually become much smaller. Making the minimum size explicit has some counter effects especially for labels (which could be clipped). Then, the size is totally arbitrary and doesn't consider font metrics and scaling and the size hints of widgets that are based on their text content, wwith the result that the text might be clipped very easily in complex layouts.

Comment: @musicamente. I agree that sometimes you might see some clipping with this code. But by and large I don't have issues. In any event, complex layouts can be tested and adjusted. I disagree that the font can become much smaller. Central widget cannot get smaller than minimumHeight and minimumWidth. And scale factors therefore cannot get smaller than 1.

Comment: @KyJames, I don't know of a graceful way to have Designer scale fonts for you. One ungraceful way, which doesn't really use Designer is to use QGraphicsWidgets and QGraphicsLayouts inside of a QGraphicsScene inside a QGraphicsView. Yuck.